# How do I convert a two-pole two-zero transfer function from the s-domain to the z-domain?

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, z-transform, transfer-function

I'm trying to convert the following IIR transfer function from the s-domain to the z-domain:
$$
H(s) = \displaystyle\frac{\frac{s^2}{\omega_z^2} + 2\zeta_z\frac s\omega_z + 1}{\frac{s^2}{\omega_p^2} + 2\zeta_p\frac{s}{\omega_p} + 1}
$$

where $\omega_z$, $\zeta_z$, $\omega_p$ and $\zeta_p$ are constants but not known ahead of time (ie. I can't use the actual values when deriving $H(z)$).

I tried using partial fraction decomposition to convert the function to a sum of single-pole filters, with the intention of substituting $s + n$ with $1 - e^{-nt}z^{-1}$ (where $n$ comes from the single pole filter and $t$ is the sample period). This ended up with an unmanageable expression that I couldn't simplify with Maxima.

Is there a more straightforward approach I can take?

Comment: Use the bilinear transformation: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform

Comment: There are a few different approaches and each of those have some variations. The partial fraction expansion shouldn’t be that hard. The denominator and numerator polynomials can be factored analytically. Do that and edit your question with those results